# (Python type hints) How to specify type being currently defined as the returned type from a method?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I would like to specify (as a type hint) the currently defined type as the return type from a method.

Here's an example:

```py
class Action(Enum):
    ignore = 0
    replace = 1
    delete = 2

    @classmethod
    # I would like something like
    # def idToObj(cls, elmId: int)->Action:
    # but I cannot specify Action as the return type
    # since it would generate the error
    # NameError: name 'Action' is not defined
    def idToObj(cls, elmId: int):
        if not hasattr(cls, '_idToObjDict'):
            cls._idToObjDict = {}
            for elm in list(cls):
                cls._idToObjDict[elm.value] = elm

        return cls._idToObjDict[elmId]
```

Ideally I would have liked to specify something like

```py
def idToObj(cls, elmId: int)->Action:
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This case is mentioned in official [type hints PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#id27):

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that
>   definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

To address this, we write:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

In your case It would be:

```
def idToObj(cls, elmId: int)->'Action':
    pass  # classmethod body
```